# removeEventListener no funciona con múltiples argumentos utilizando React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

No puedo quitar el **`EventListener`** del click izquierdo y, después de llamar a **`removeEventListener`**, el **console log** continua mostrándose después de clicar en cualquier lugar de la pantalla.

He hecho algunas pruebas y el problema es el **bind** de **`handleClickOutside`** porque si llamo a la función sin argumentos, **`removeEventListener`** funciona.

**PD**: No sé como tipar el evento y el **`SetIsModalOpened (setState)`**.

Mi código:

```
  // TODO: change typo of "e" and "setIsModalOpened"
  const showModal = (e: any, isModalOpened: boolean, setIsModalOpened: any): void => {
    const elementId = e.currentTarget.id;
    if (!isModalOpened) {
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => handleClickOutside(e, elementId, setIsModalOpened));
    }
    setIsModalOpened(!isModalOpened);
  }

  // TODO: change typo of "e" and "setIsModalOpened"
  const handleClickOutside = (e: any, elementId: string, setIsModalOpened: any) => {
    if (e.target.id !== elementId) {
      setIsModalOpened(false); 
    }
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown', (e) => handleClickOutside(e, elementId, setIsModalOpened));
  }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Please translate your Question, this is Stack Overflow in Spanish

Comment: Perdón, es la primera vez que uso esta plataforma. Gracias por el comentario!

Comment: Por favor no pongas capturas de código, pon el código.

Comment: Hecho! muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás pasando dos funciones anónimas `(e) =>` distintas, las cuales dentro invocan a `handleClickOutside`.
Lo que debes hacer es pasar `handleClickOutside` como parámetro de los listeners, algo como:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
```

Si quieres pasar parámetros adicionales a tu función, podrías usar [`handleClickOutside.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) para atar el contexto de `this` o los parámetros que requieras. 
Aplicado a tu problema (excluyendo React/Typescript)

```js
const handleClickOutside = (e, elementId, setIsModalOpened, otro) => {
  console.log(this); // saldra `undefined` por el contexto en que se ejecuta en S.O.
  console.log(`1:${e}`);
  console.log(`2:${elementId}`);
  console.log(`3:${setIsModalOpened}`);
  console.log(`4:${otro}`);
};
handleClickOutside.bind(
  this,
  'tu evento',
  'el elementId correspondiente',
  'si está abierto o no tu modal'
)('cualquier cosa extra que quieras agregar');
```

Comment: La cuestión es que usando Hooks y también arrow functions ya se hace el bindeo de la función. De esa forma no puedo hacerlo. Gracias!!

Comment: @user142753 la arrow function no aplicaría, porque lo que te sugiero en la respuesta es que las saques. Y hooks tampoco tiene relación, porque lo que estás tratando de manejar está fuera del contexto de los hooks. Quizás no me expliqué correctamente, pero revisa mi respuesta actualizada.